# Why browsers won't handle response from my http-server

Tags: java, android, http, tcp, netty-socketio

I'm trying to make [Netty-socketio](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) to work under android OS. The issue i've met during debugging is that the response generated on android device is not recognized by any browser. Here're two pictures of Fiddler composed GET requests:

The first one is a response from socket.io server that runs on port 3000 under nodejs from termux terminal. This server I implemented based on [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/building-a-node-js-application-on-android-part-1-termux-vim-and-node-js-dfa90c28958f/) post (it works absulutely fine, but I need socket.io server inside of my android app)
[image: this]

The second one is a response from Netty-socketio (running on 3002 port)
[image]

And here's what get in browsers:
3000 port (termux, nodejs)
[image]
3002 port (netty-socketio)
[image]
Just in case I compared these two requests in wireshark and couldn't find any hint.
[image]

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: double-check the conten-length...

Comment: Hey Julian, Thank you for idea, but I think the content length is OK. I think so because I previously had an issue with content length. And when it was wrong Fiddler highlighted such requests and when I checked its properties it was saying something like "violation of http: header content-length is N bytes, but actual is X... Also, Wireshark didn't recognize such requests as HTTP. But in my case as you can see on the screen it is HTTP.

Comment: Check what Firefox says...